# Nested parallelism with R future

Tags: r, foreach, future, r-future

I'm trying to read multiple large csv files with nested parallelism with future.

I have a single machine with 32 cores, and I want to set up nested parallel (5 by 6) with outer 5 process with 6 cores each. I'm trying to utilize implicit parallelism from `data.table::fread(.., nThreads = 6)`.

The R package `future` provides nested parallelism, and I've tried

```
library(future)
plan(list(tweak(multisession, workers = 5), tweak(multisession, workers = 6)))
```

but above is actually using only 1 cores for each subprocess:

```
plan(list(tweak(multisession, workers = 5), 
          tweak(multisession, workers = 6)))
registerDoFuture()
foreach(i = 1:5) %dopar%  {
  availableCores()
}

[[1]]
mc.cores 
       1 

[[2]]
mc.cores 
       1 

[[3]]
mc.cores 
       1 

[[4]]
mc.cores 
       1 

[[5]]
mc.cores 
       1
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Why not give [vroom](https://vroom.r-lib.org/) a try. There is no need to get hands dirty via messing around with all the details in `future`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Futureverse maintainer here)

> ... but above is actually using only 1 cores for each subprocess:

I see the misunderstanding here. You want to use `nbrOfWorkers()` (from **[future](https://future.futureverse.org/)**) here instead of `availableCores()` (from **[parallelly](https://parallelly.futureverse.org/)** - reexported as-is from **future**).  This will give you what you'd expected:

```r
> foreach(i = 1:5) %dopar% {
  nbrOfWorkers()
}
[[1]]
[1] 6
...
[[5]]
[1] 6
```

The reason for `availableCores()` returning one (1) is because the **future** framework tries to prevent nested parallelization by mistake. It does this by setting options and environment variables that controls number of parallel workers and CPU cores, including `options(mc.cores = 1L)`.  This is correctly picked up by `availableCores()`.  This prevents, for instance, a package that uses `y <- mclapply(X, FUN)`, `cl <- makeCluster(avaiableCores())`, or `plan(multisession)` from running in parallel if already running in a parallel worker.  In contrast, `nbrOfWorkers()` reflects the number of workers specified by `plan()`.  In your case, we have `plan(multisession, workers = 6)` set in the parallel workers, from the second level in `plan(list(tweak(multisession, workers = 5), tweak(multisession, workers = 6)))`.

To convince yourself you're indeed are running in parallel with your setup, you can adopt one of the examples in https://future.futureverse.org/articles/future-3-topologies.html.

Now, parallel *threads* are not the same as parallel *processes* (aka parallel workers).  You can think of *threads* as a much lower-level parallelization mechanism.  Importantly, the **future** framework does *not* constrain the number of *threads* used in parallel workers, including the number of parallel threads that **data.table** uses.  Because of this, you need to explicitly call:

```r
data <- data.table::fread(.., nThreads = 6)
```

or, if you want to be agile to the current settings,

```r
data <- data.table::fread(.., nThreads = nbrOfWorkers())
```

to avoid over-parallelization.  Alternatively, you can reconfigure **data.table** as:

```r
## Set the number of parallel threads used by 'data.table'
## (the default is to use all physical CPU cores)
data.table::setDTthreads(nbrOfWorkers())
data <- data.table::fread(..;)
```

BTW, in **[doFuture](https://doFuture.futureverse.org/)** (>= 1.0.0), you longer need `registerDoFuture()` if you replace `%dopar%` with `%dofuture%`.  So, the gist of reading lots of CSV files in parallel is:

```r
library(doFuture)
plan(list(tweak(multisession, workers = 5), 
          tweak(multisession, workers = 6)))

files <- dir(pattern = "*.csv$")
res <- foreach(file = files) %dofuture% {
  data.table::setDTthreads(nbrOfWorkers())
  data.table::fread(file)
}
```

With all that said, note that your bottleneck will probably be the file system rather than the CPU.  When you parallelize reading files, you might overwhelm the file system and end up slowing down the file reading rather than speeding it up.  Sometimes it gets faster to read two-three files in parallel, but with more it becomes counterproductive.  So, you need to benchmark with different number of parallel workers.

Moreover, these days, there are R packages that are highly-specialized for reading data files into R efficiently.  Some of them supports reading multiple files efficiently.  The **vroom** package is one such example.

Comment: Perhaps a silly question, but in this case is the required number of cores 6*5 = 30 or 6*5 + 5 = 35?

Comment: There are no such things as "silly questions".  When using `plan(multsession, workers = 3)`, there are indeed 1 + 5 = 6 R processes running. Ideally, the main R process will be mostly idle, because it just sits there waiting for the 5 workers to send back the results.  Analogously, with `plan(list(tweak(multisession, workers=5), tweak(multisession, workers=6)))`, there are 1 + 5*(1 + 6) = 1 + 5*7 = 1 + 35 = 36 R processes running, but 1 + 5*1 = 6 of them are idle because they just wait for their "child" workers to return results. The remaining 5*6 process will do all the work ("use the cores")

Comment: So let's say I was working on a SLURM cluster and I had to reserve cores, it sounds like I could get away with reserving 30 without breaking anything, but might prefer to reserve 36?

Comment: Yes, it's sufficient to reserve 30 CPU cores ("slots"). That's what I do on our Slurm & SGE clusters. FWIW, it's likely your cluster is configured so your jobs run such that they can only access the number of CPU cores requested. This is done via Linux CGroup and means that no matter how hard you try, you will never be able to use more than you got access too. In other words, those 36 R processes will only get a sandbox with 30 cores to play with. It's not worth asking for 36 slots, because then it's likely that you only end up using 30/36 = 83% of the CPU resource allotted to the job.